# Washing machine in apartment

Tags: building-design, building-physics, construction-management

I live on a second floor of 4 story apartments building and I'm planning to change my old washer+dryer tower for a new one, however it is bigger and heavier. I'm worried that the weight could cause a problem.

The new weight will be 315 lbs (I believe the previous one was around 255 lbs). I do see that new towers are around this size and weight, so I suppose it should be ok, but not sure about the max weight that buildings are supposed to handle.

Comment: can two people stand next to each other without breaking through the floor in your apartment? ... that same weight is spread over a much larger area than four footprints

Comment: (Depending on the design of the 'feet' that are built into the washer...) If you're really worried, pop it on some blocks of wood to spread the load.